# Values in Dataframe to diff rows if it is list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for solution that can make the new dataframe if on the location of dataframe has presence of list object. If it is a list than add only those elements in diffrent rows without affecting other data.

```
# Sample dataframe
No.   Name    Skill    Exp
0     ABC     [a,b,c]  [0,2,3]
1     XYZ     [e,f]    [3,4]
2     EFG     h        2
3     PQR     g        3
```

but I want to convert the dataframe as follows:

```
# Output Dataframe
No.   Name    Skill    Exp
0     ABC     a        0
              b        2
              c        3
1     XYZ     e        3
              f        4
2     EFG     h        2
3     PQR     g        3
```

Comment: Please check perfect [maxu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/2901002) answer

Comment: Thanks. But it is also repeating all other values.

Comment: Can you explian more? Do you think first 2 columns?

Comment: First 2 columns are Name and Skills they Possess and depend on their expertise there would be rating from 0-5.